# Run command in linux vm in azure using python sdk changed?

Tags: python, azure

Recently i upgraded to latest Azure Python SDK and found the command has changed to begin_run_command, but when i tried this, result did not return anything, and status shows "InProgress"

```
run_command_parameters = {
  'command_id': 'RunShellScript', # For linux, don't change it
  'script': [
      'ls /tmp'
  ]
```

}

```
poller = client.virtual_machines.run_command(
    resource_group_name,
    vm_name,
    run_command_parameters
```

)

```
result = poller.result()  # Blocking till executed
print(result.value[0].message)  # stdout/stderr
```

is this a bug or i missed anything ?

Comment: Are you really asking here about changes in different versions of a library that you're using? And you don't even say which were the two versions involved or provide a [mcve]. Please, start with the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems everything works perfectly on my side, please try the code below:

```
from azure.identity import AzureCliCredential
from azure.mgmt.compute import ComputeManagementClient
import os

# Acquire a credential object using CLI-based authentication.
credential = AzureCliCredential()

resource_group = '<your rg name>'
vm_name='<your vm name>'
subscription_id = '<your azure subID>'

run_command_parameters = {
    'command_id': 'RunShellScript', # For linux, don't change it
    'script': [
        'ls /tmp'
        ]
    }


compute_client = ComputeManagementClient(
        credential=credential,
        subscription_id=subscription_id
    )

poller = compute_client.virtual_machines.begin_run_command(
    resource_group,
    vm_name,
    run_command_parameters);

result = poller.result()  # Blocking till executed
print(result.value[0].message)  # stdout/stderr
```

Test result on my side:

[image]

It will take some time to get the command result.

Comment: The problem i had earlier probably due to incompatible package versions in my local machine. Now it worked after some clean up.